# rpy2 how to call as.matrix()

Tags: rpy2

I am using rpy2 to call some R function from python. The R function returns a dist object. How do I call `as.matrix()` from python on the result the R code returns?

```
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
Rsession = rpy2.robjects.r
tsclust = importr('TSclust')

X= np.random.random((5,5))
result = Rsession.diss( X , "ACF", p=0.05)
```

`result` is of the class dist. I would like a square distance matrix, which I can achieve by calling `as.matrix()` on the result . How do I do this with rpy2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do it just like that:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

base = importr('base')
base.as_matrix(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one solution. It's not pretty but it works. We define a custom function that calls `as.matrix`

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import STAP
mfunc = 'myasmatrix <- function(dobj){return(as.matrix(dobj))}'
myasmatrix = STAP(mfunc, "myasmatrix")

np.array(myasmatrix.myasmatrix(rres))
>>> array([[0.        , 0.0663193 , 0.01159857, 0.14378692, 0.10069314],
   [0.0663193 , 0.        , 0.06064907, 0.07965314, 0.03511945],
   [0.01159857, 0.06064907, 0.        , 0.13898505, 0.095319  ],
   [0.14378692, 0.07965314, 0.13898505, 0.        , 0.04757353],
   [0.10069314, 0.03511945, 0.095319  , 0.04757353, 0.        ]])
```